# push data from text file to Kafka continuously

Tags: apache-kafka

i have create a simple producer that read data from textfile and send it to kafka

```
try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new      FileReader(getInputFileName()))) {
        String line = br.readLine();
        while (line != null) {
            KeyedMessage<String, String> data = new KeyedMessage<String, String>(getTopic(), null, line);
            producer.send(data);
            System.out.println(line);
            //Thread.sleep(200l);
            line = br.readLine();
```

and it is working perfectly but it only buffer the data at that time and send it , so if some one change the Textfile and add new line , these new data will not be sent to the kafka

i need to know if i can do something that will continuously capture the new lines that inserted to the textfile and send it automatically to kafka .

any help ?

Comment: Did you consider using Kafka Connect: http://kafka.apache.org/documentation#connect

Answer (score 0):

From version 0.9, Kafka Connect is part of Apache Kafka.

Also by default it support `FileStreamSource` as one of the source connector.

For detailed example check this [link](http://howtoprogram.xyz/2016/07/10/apache-kafka-connect-example/)